# Comma or Semicolon in "Assisted with X(,) including cataloging Y and assisting with planning Z"?

Tags: commas, semicolons

I'm wondering if the comma placed after *event* is being used appropriately or if it should be replaced with a semicolon. This is part of a resume so I am trying to keep this information to one sentence.

> Assisted with preparations for the 40th anniversary fundraising event, including cataloging auction items and assisting with planning the 40th anniversary luncheon

Comment: It's correct. Do not use a semicolon. (semicolon is one word; hyphenate it if you like.)

Comment: You can't use a semicolon. The clause beginning with "including' can't stand on its own.

Comment: In its current form, this question is too localised to be of use to anybody else and is probably also off-topic as it's essentially a proof-reading question. Marking it as such.

Comment: There's a U in *cataloguing*. (It doesn't matter how you punctuate incomplete sentences in bullet-point style, but you still have to spell right.)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend re-wording this item in
your resume.  How about the following?

"Assisted with preparations for 
   the 40th anniversary fundraising 
   event by cataloging items and 
   by helping to plan the luncheon."

(the repeated "40th anniversary" 
   in your entry is not necessary, is 
   it?)